# Amazon ec2 instance sendmail

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, service, sendmail

I am using amazon server. But php mail function not working on it. I am not able to send mail using Sendmail without Amazon SES. 
It show the message when i use the command "service sendmail status"

"send mail is stopped"

"sm-client dead but pid file exists".

I tried to start sendmail using "service sendmail start" command then i got the message,

Starting sendmail:  4.0.0 /etc/mail/sendmail.cf: line 87: fileclass: cannot o
pen '/etc/mail/local-host-names': World writable directory
 4.0.0 /etc/mail/sendmail.cf: line 596: fileclass: cannot open '/etc/mail/trusted-users': World writable directory

Answer (score 0):

### Sendmail: too broad write permissions to configuration directories

Sendmail refuses to use (confuguration) files with too broad write permissions as a security precaution. Remove write permissions for every system user from '/etc/mail/', '/etc/' and '/'.

Comment: I have removed the write permission from the 'etc/mail/' and '/etc/', still i got the same error.

Comment: Have you restarted/HUPed sendmail daemon(s) after fixing too broad permissions?

Comment: Could you include result of `ls -ld /etc/mail /etc /` to your question?

Comment: I have solved the problem using postfix. but now i got new issue.
I got this error when I try to login
-bash: /etc/profile: Permission denied.
I tried to solve this problem by following step.
Create new instance. Assign old instance volume to new instance. Login into new instance and tried to change permission on sudoers. 
But I don't know how exactly change permission on sudoers and how to solve this issue.